# How can I pass more detailed messages through my error view?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to figure out how to pass more details into my error view.  Right now, it's just very generic.

I'd like to pass in the data for `scheduledWedding.EventStart` and `scheduledWedding.EventEnd` so that I can see what wedding dates are causing the issue. I tried adding both values to the view, but that just really throws a nasty error message because it didn't know what those values are.

How can I add that type of data to my Error view?

Thanks!

Here is my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> ScheduleWeddingEvents(DateTime start, DateTime end)
{
    foreach(var scheduledWedding in EventScheduling.GenerateEvent(eventGroup))
    {
        if(scheduledWedding.EventStart <= DateTime.Now || scheduledWedding.EventEnd <= DateTime.Now)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        if(scheduledWedding.EventStart > scheduledWedding.EventEnd)
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        result = EventMaker(result);
    }

    return View(result);
}
```

Here is the Error model:

using System;

```
namespace LET.Panopto.Scheduler.Models
{
    public class ErrorViewModel
    {
        public string RequestId { get; set; }

        public bool ShowRequestId => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RequestId);
    }
}
```

And here is the error view:

```
@model ErrorViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Error";
}

<h1 class="text-danger">Error.</h1>
<h2 class="text-danger">An error occurred while processing your request.</h2>

@if (Model.ShowRequestId)
{
    <p>
        <strong>Request ID:</strong> <code>@Model.RequestId</code>
    </p>
}

<h3>Development Mode</h3>
<p>
    Swapping to <strong>Development</strong> environment will display more detailed information about the error that occurred.
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Development environment should not be enabled in deployed applications</strong>, as it can result in sensitive information from exceptions being displayed to end users. For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the <strong>ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT</strong> environment variable to <strong>Development</strong>, and restarting the application.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send data to the view you could send in the view model you already have (and your view is using) with the extra date properties defined in it.

Example (given you added properties for the dates in your `ErrorViewModel.cs`):

```
if (scheduledWedding.EventStart > scheduledWedding.EventEnd)
        {
            var errorViewModel = new ErrorViewModel
            {
                EventStart = scheduledWedding.EventStart,
                EventEnd = scheduledWedding.EventEnd,
                //Set other data you need to have in your error view
            };

            return View("Error", errorViewModel);
        }
```